# ngTagsInput Get tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using the below `ngTagsInput` for tagging in my AngularJS.

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api

```
<tags-input id="SearchFor" name="SearchFor" placeholder="FreeText Search" class="form-control ti-input-sm" ng-model="FreeText" on-tag-added="ActionFreeText(FreeText)" use-strings="true"></tags-input>
```

**Expecting the tags in the form of arrayto be return in ActionFreeText**

```
$scope.ActionFreeText = function (value) {
    console.log('value' + value);
}
```

The value I am getting in ActionFreeText is 'undefined'. Any idea how can I get the tags entered in my ActionFreeText function.

Comment: "The new tag is available as $tag.", so you can do `on-tag-added="ActionFreeText($tag)"`

Comment: @devqon tried that but the value is still undefined.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: It does work, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d48av64L/1/)

Comment: @devqon You absolutely right. I had a type error was using $tags instead to $tag. One last question: ow do i get all the tags in an array or something instead of only getting the last entered tag?

Comment: That is your `ng-model` as you can see in the jsfiddle. But on the moment that `on-tag-added` is triggered the newly added tag is not yet pushed to the `ng-model`

Comment: But even when I have 3 tags on my input box It only pushed the newly entered item to ActionFreeText function

Comment: Yes that is correct, the rest is in your property which is referenced by `ng-model`, in your case `$scope.FreeText`

Comment: Ok great. Not sure how do I mark your reply as answer as its only in comments.